# SQLite - android - display data from existing DB

Tags: android, sqlite

i have always this prooblem , i can't display DB's data in my Activity !

[image]

To get started i tried to do something like this : my class **BDHelper** :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lm";
   public static final String EMP_TABLE = "contacts";
   public static final String _id = "id";
   public static final String E_NAME = "name";
   public static final String E_AGE = "age";
   public static final String E_DEPT = "dept";


   public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
   {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      db.execSQL(
      "create table contacts " +
      "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text,email text, street text,place text)"
      );
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
      onCreate(db);
   }

   public boolean insertContact  (String name, String age, String dept)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put("name", name);
      contentValues.put("age", age);    
      contentValues.put("dept", dept);
      db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
      return true;
   }

   public Cursor getData(int id){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
      return res;
   }

   public int numberOfRows(){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, EMP_TABLE);
      return numRows;
   }

   public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name,String age, String dept)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put("name", name);
      contentValues.put("age", age);    
      contentValues.put("dept", dept);
      db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
      return true;
   }

  /* public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      return db.delete("contacts", 
      "id = ? ", 
      new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
   }*/

   public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
   {
      ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
      res.moveToFirst();

      while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
         array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EMP_TABLE)));
         res.moveToNext();
      }
   return array_list;
   }
```

And I'm trying to display it in the main-activity , that's why i did that :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";
    private ListView obj;
    DataBaseHelper mydb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mydb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        ArrayAdapter<?> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I always get the same result: an empty Activity. I tried in other ways, and looked at other questions with similar problems, I just wanna get where I missed it here  !

Comment: `arrayAdapter` is empty... So why do you expect data to be there?

Comment: Perhaps you could call a method on `mydb` to get some data?

Comment: **ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
 ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);**

i used this , but it says : warning , and it needs to suppressWaarning

Comment: It has a warning because you didn't type the adapter or the list. `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: it worked for the Warning , but still showing nothing !

Comment: According to the image, your table is named `EMP_TABLE`, not `contacts`, so you are getting 0 records

Comment: what should i do ? replace it in all the file ? you sure ?

Comment: I would recommend you drop and recreate the table. Your image clearly says "Table: EMP_TABLE"

Comment: So you say you've put the database file into the assets folder, but I do not see the code that actually reads that database file. It would appear you are making a new database. You may want to look at [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: i thought that this code does :
**public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lm";**

Comment: `super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);` will create an new database file in the app's private data, not the assets

Comment: i just google it , you're right, but i can't find a solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - create a class called Contact.java and create set and get methods for " "id", name", "age" and "dept".

Second- go to yout DbAdapter class and put this code in getAllContacts()

```
 ArrayList<Contact> listContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + CONTACT ;
    mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId((cursor.getLong(0)));
            contact.setName((cursor.getString(1)));
            contact.setDept(cursor.getString(2));
            listContacts.add(note);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return listContacts;
```

Dont forget use the cursor.get.. according columns order.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create your table in the following manner

```
db.execSQL(
          "create table if not exists contacts " +
          "(id integer primary key, name text, phone text, email text, street text, place text );   "
);
```

Change your getAllContacts to something like this

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
   {
      ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
     if (res.getCount() != 0) {
            for (res.moveToFirst(); !res.isAfterLast(); res.moveToNext()) {
         array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(EMP_TABLE)));
      } 
     }
   return array_list;
   }
```

You need to change your onCreate to something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mydb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mydb.getAllContacts);

    obj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

I haven't tried this but hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your help , but it doesn't work , always the Empty thing :/

plus you missed () here :

**ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mydb.getAllContacts);**

Comment: Sorry for that. An ArrayAdapter<> usually takes a String[] as a parameter. You should try with that. Please check the updated code

Comment: NOt Working , please look closely to the code to find the issue ,

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    db.execSQL(
          "create table contacts " +
          "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text,email text, street text,place text)  ;   "
);
```

See the semi-colon between `text)` & `"`? That's missing so your creation never finishes.

Comment: The image shows there is data and a table. Plus, the semi-colon is not important for single statements

Comment: i try to use an existing DB , not create one , do i mmust delete that tho ?

Comment: @cricket_007, do you have a reference I could review? the ones I am finding all say you do need it in most cases. **S'ed Sckizo**, how did you get that database there?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. I just don't think that this is the complete answer.

Comment: i create it using DB browser , then i put it in the asset folder , because it's just a simple example , i need to deal with something bigger

Comment: @cricket_007, fair point, it's worth pointing out though that completeness would depend entirely on whether this was the only issue, maybe I should have pointed this error out in the comments instead.  **S'ed Sckizo**, I see, ideally you want to try to add it programmatically to ensure your `DBHelper`'s `onCreate()` is actually working.

Comment: i didn't get what you're tryna say